# Coordinate extraction using Tesseract 4.0

Tags: c#, tesseract

I am developing an application that will be used to automate invoice indexing. One use-case of my application is to extract tables from scanned documents. To do this, I need to extract the coordinates of all the words in the text (if this is not possible, I could use the coordinates of the letters as well). I plan on using Tesseract 4.0 for C# and I wanted to know if this is possible.

Thank you

Comment: Anything is possible if you have enough time.  I use to work for a company that did paper form processing and I can tell you this is not a simple problem to tackle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get bounding box for each recognized word . Below is a sample code using [C# Tesseract wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract).

```
 //intialize the TesseractEngine
  using (var engine = new TesseractEngine("path to tessdata folder", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
  {
      //image here is Bitmap on which OCR is to be performed
      using (var page = engine.Process(image, PageSegMode.Auto))
      {
          using (var iterator = page.GetIterator())
          {

              iterator.Begin();
              do
              {
                  string currentWord = iterator.GetText(PageIteratorLevel.Word);
                  //do something with bounds 
                  iterator.TryGetBoundingBox(PageIteratorLevel.Word, out Rect bounds);                                   
               }
               while (iterator.Next(PageIteratorLevel.Word));
          }
      }
   }
```

You can now store the bounds for each word and write your logic to map them to table row/columns based on their bounding box (this is the difficult part and if your table format is neat , you should be able to get it working with some effort.). Also, consider looking at [Tabula](https://tabula.technology/) library to see if it can solve problem at hand .

Answer (score 0):

Dim Region As Rect

```
        Using iterator = page.GetIterator()
            iterator.Begin()
            Do
                Dim searchStr = iterator.GetText(PageIteratorLevel.Word)
                For Each k As String In listOfSearch
                    If searchStr.IndexOf(k, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
                        If iterator.TryGetBoundingBox(PageIteratorLevel.Word, Region) Then
                            Dim systemDrawingRect As New System.Drawing.Rectangle(Region.X1, Region.Y1, Region.Width, Region.Height)
                            pdfPage = HighlightTextOnImage(pdfPage, systemDrawingRect)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next

            Loop While iterator.[Next](PageIteratorLevel.Word)

        End Using
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**